# passing a numeric as a character to a function in R

Tags: arrays, r, function, class, numeric

I have the following function in R:

```
function.class<-function(CLASS){
  ma<<-as.matrix(subset(dft, class == as.character(CLASS)))
  #  ma[ma==" "]<<-0
  ma<-apply(ma, 1,as.numeric,na.rm=TRUE)
  ma<-t(ma[-(1:5),])
  print(CLASS)
  a<-1-colMeans(ma,na.rm=TRUE)
  b<-colSums(!is.na(ma))
  c<-rep(0,length(a)+length(b))
  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    c[(2*i-1)]<-a[i]
    c[(2*i)]<-b[i]
  }
  return(c)

}
```

I'm passing it the following (with context):

```
z<-matrix(0,length(unique(dft$class)),2*(ncol(dft)-5))
name<-as.matrix(unique(dft$class))
for (j in 1:length(unique(dft$class))){
  z[j,]<-function.form(name[j,])
}
```

Here's some facts about `name`:

```
> name
     [,1] 
[1,] "200"
[2,] "20" 
[3,] "100"
[4,] "320"
> summary(name)
   V1   
 100:1  
 20 :1  
 200:1  
 320:1  
> typeof(name)
[1] "character"
```

However, when I run the loop, it makes `ma` into a 0x46 logical matrix, but if I manually run what the for loops is trying to do (i.e. put replace `CLASS` with `name[1,]`,`name[2,]`,`name[3,]`, etc. in the function and copy and paste it into the console), it makes a `ma` into a 195x41 double matrix.

Here is what dft looks like

```
dft<-c(rep(NA,382*46))
pass<-sample(382*46,382*15,replace=FALSE)
fail<-sample(382*46,382*15,replace=FALSE)
dft[c(pass)]<-1
dft[c(fail)]<-0

dft<-matrix(as.character(q,382,46))
dft<-as.data.frame(q)
names(dft)<-as.character(1:46)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say, since we don't have `dft`, so we can't actually reproduce this.

Comment: Never use `<<-`. And is the function name `function.class` a joke? Anyway, you should tell us what the function is supposed to do and provide some minimal input data as well as the expected output.

Comment: Ok...I won't use <<-...and function.class is not a joke.  I've added a ham fisted way of reproducing what dft looks like.  I'm trying to create a matrix (or two, in this incantation) that alternates columns between the average of each column in dft (excluding NAs) and the sum of all column entries that are not NAs in dft.

Comment: The point Roland is making is that "class" has a specific meaning in `R` (and most other programming languages) and you should not be abusing it this way.  What do you expect to happen when you assign semirandom character strings to the `class` attribute of your matrix?

Comment: Oh my goodness...I see what you mean!  That's why nothing worked in it...I renamed function.class to something else and now it works wonderfully.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3033594 , you could write up an answer to your own question ...